# Guest session 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

Good morning all I work for an agency that provides computers for public access to do job search and resume building. I currently have 5 PC's that run Ubuntu 14.04.

My question is there a way to save web links to the desk top on the guest session with out them being erased after the clients log off?

Any help will be appreciated

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Probably not. But  .... create a script that copies them over to another location and when booting put them bavk on the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the answer to your questions is [here.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizeGuestSession) Please refer to the section of the article labled "Save files on Disk"

You will also need to create the Special Purpose User